# Inserting a single row from different databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

To start off we have two databases. One called TOk and the other called test2. test2 is a backup of TOk. A situation occurred in which a single row was deleted accidentally from the TOk database in the hazards table. I just want to know if there is a way to copy that record single row to another database. HazID is the unique identifier in that particular table so would something like. Both databases reside on the same instance.

```
INSERT INTO Tok.hazard.dbo *
Select * From Test2.hazard.dbo
Where HazID=(the specific ID of the missing record)
```

Is this close?

Basically expect the record to be copied back into the live database.

Comment: By databases do you mean data engines? If not, why have you tagged MySQL and SQL Server and which are you *really* using? The 2 are very different products.

Comment: Are you sure your schema is called `hazard` and your table called `dbo`? I suspect they're the other way around - you should be selecting/inserting from `YourDb.dbo.Hazard`, judging by the column named `HazID`

Comment: Don't use `*` and write all the columns in both the insert list and in the select list, on the same order. The insert should work fine unless you have an identity column (SQL Server) or other objects that work validating data or the such, in which case you should do some additional work if it fails.

Comment: @Bridge you are also correct Tok.dbo.Hazard being the table in both the source and destination.

Comment: @EzLo there are so many columns :( I have to write all of them? Jeez. I'll get to it though

Comment: To add to Ezlo's comment, you don't _have_ to write all the columns, but it's a good idea from a long-term maintenance perspective. If the order or number of columns in either table changes, it'll silently break your code. Most people consider it good programming practice to list all the columns as it removes this maintenance headache and also makes the code more readable (in terms of seeing exactly what is being copied to what). If this is just a one-off query then don't bother.

Comment: So it turns out that one of the columns is an identity column. I ran a set Identity_Inset Tok.dbo.Hazards On and it worked

Comment: @JoeBlack some tips. Assuming SQL Server, and you're using SQL Server Management Studio, a couple of helpers for you - if you expand the columns folder under a table, you can drag the folder into the script window and it'll copy all column names out for you. Alternatively, you can use the query designer (available from the menus/right click/ctrl+shift+Q) which will expand the column names for you.